# How to use font awesome inside laravel Voyager?

Tags: laravel, fonts, font-awesome, voyager

is it possible to use font awesome in laravel voyager? If so how do I go about using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding your css from `config/voyager.php` in `additional_css`

Install Font Awesome using `npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save-dev`

Create laravel mix file `resources\sass\font-awesome.scss` and import fontawesome file in that mix

```
//Font Awesome

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

In `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')

    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')

    .sass('resources/sass/font-awesome.scss', 'public/css');
```

`npm run dev` compile css file using this command for dev environment

**config\voyager.php**

```
'additional_css' => [

    'css/font-awesome.css',

],
```

Comment: it works but the icons are not displayed correctly

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: a kind of comma

Comment: Take a ss of that and update in your question